# SQL Keep only records with time after

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a Nr, DateTime, Status

If booked out status is 1 if booked in status is 0.

I need to get a list daily where I want to see if it was booked out on the day but not return.

I need to look for status 1, and after that time if there is not a status 0.

I tried this.

```
SELECT A1.Number, A1.Time TimeOut, A2.Time TimeIn  
FROM dbo.Items A1 LEFT JOIN dbo.Items A2 ON A1.Number = A2.Number 
    AND A2.Time !< A1.Time 
    AND A1.State = 1 
    AND A2.State = 0 
WHERE A2.Time IS NULL
```

The output should be:

```
Nr : TimeOut             : TimeIn : 

10   2017/09/15 12:00     NULL
15   2017/09/15 15:45     NULL
```

The data is:

```
NR  : Status : Date
5      0       2017/09/15 09:00
10     0       2017/09/15 12:00
5      1       2017/09/15 13:00
15     0       2017/09/15 15:45
```

Comment: Hi I am using MS SQL 2008 server

Comment: add alos a proper data sample  ..

Comment: Added the sample data

Comment: You have syntax errors in your sql statement. 1 too many (trailing) `,` in your SELECT and when doing a not equals the syntax is `<>` not `!<`

Comment: Also you seem to be joining 2 tables (Alarms, Items) but only supplied sample data for one of them? Please update your question to include data from both tables and mark which table each sample data set is.

Comment: Only one input, I edited question to dbo.Items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select the row where  NR have not date for status OUT eg:

```
select NR, Date as TimeOut, NULL as TimeIn
FROM dbo.Alarms
    where (NR) NOT in (
      select a.NR 
       from dbo.Alarms a
       INNER JOIN (
        select NR, Date 
        from  dbo.Alarms
        where status = 1
       ) t on t.NR = a.NR and Date(t.date) = date(a.date)
    )
```

Comment: I get invalid column on NR and Date

Comment: I have added FROM dbo.Alarms after Timein, it works, thanks for your help. Please edit your answer and I will accept it as right

Comment: Ops  ...     @Danie   many .. thanks  .. answer  update with  proper from clause